# Flamenco guitar strings

Tags: guitar, strings, history, lutherie, flamenco

Before the invention of nylon, from what material were strings made for use by  flamenco players? I have tried different search engines and forae but found no answer or similar question.

Answer (score 6):

In Europe, stringed instruments (harps, guitars, violins) have used strings made from animal gut for millenia.

The lower strings of a guitar were sometimes made with gut wrapped around a silk core.

Here are the [icky details](https://acousticmusic.org/research/guitar-information/guitar-strings/).

Comment: Fascinating. Wonder if someone found out how to make them by accident. Some accident! Seriously, why would anybody do all that?

Comment: It's like, who first ate snails?

Comment: Whoever it was, we can't know their name, because by the time we'd thought of naming people, we'd already been eating snails for 27,000 years.